# dplyr inside a function: apply function to column, when function and colname are parameters

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that accepts a column name and a(n anonymous) function as paramters. The function should use `dplyr` to mutate the column identified by the column name by applying the function.

For example, if used as below, the function should mutate column `a` of `data`.

```
data <- tbl_df(data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5))
MyFunction(data, 'a', function(x) as.character(as.integer((x)))
```

I came up with the code below, but I cannot figure out how to construct `fun.call`:

```
MyFunction <- function(df, colname, fun) {
  fun.call <- ???
  df %>%
    ... other dplyr commands ...
    mutate_(.dots = setNames(fun.call, colname)
    ... other dplyr commands ...
}
```

How can I make this work?

I want to use `dplyr`, because my real-world-function contains a longer chain of dplyr commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need dplyr?

```
MyFunction <- function(df, colname, fun)
{
     df[[colname]] <- fun(df[[colname]])
     df
}
```

Comment: Fair point. My real-world problem involves a longer chain of dplyr commands connected with pipes and I'd rather just add another link to that chain. I should have added that to the question in the first place. My bad.

Comment: @severin You can add the function as defined here into a pipeline just fine.

Comment: I am looking for something that I can add to a pipeline inside MyFunction and I was wondering whether there is a way to do it with mutate, but of course, I could define a new function as per your suggestion and use it in that pipeline. That just seems overly verbose to me.

Comment: @severin You can put the `%>%` inside the `function() {...}`, or outside. Up to you.